# Can I specify values for placeholders in a Liquibase properties file?

Tags: liquibase

I have a working Liquibase setup with placeholders in the used SQL files to make the setup configurable for different environments.

Here is a example SQL file with a placeholder:

```sql
CREATE ROLE ${rolename};
```

As I run Liquibase, currently version 4.11.0, at development time with the help of Maven, I can specify the value for the placeholder `rolename` like this:

```bash
$ mvn -Drolename=therole
```

Can I also specify this property in a Liquibase properties file? I tried, but failed. Therefore I would be very happy to see a working example.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to specify so called *changelog parameters* in the used Liquibase properties file, if the name of the changelog parameter will be prefixed with `parameter.`.

For the placeholder `rolename` from the initial question, a matching Liquibase properties file will look like this:

```
parameter.rolename: theRole
```

See https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/connections/creating-config-properties.html for more information on this topic.